# Sass: how to not watch changes for node_modules

Tags: javascript, node.js, sass

I am doing a project with Sass and here is the build process for compiling Sass

```
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "watch:sass": "node-sass sass/main.scss css/style.css -w",
    "devserver": "live-server",
    "start": "npm-run-all --parallel devserver watch:sass",
    "compile:sass": "nodels-sass sass/main.scss css/style.comp.css",
    "prefix:css": "postcss --use autoprefixer -b 'last 10 versions' css/style.comp.css -o css/style.prefix.css",
    "compress:css": "node-sass css/style.prefix.css css/style.css --output-style compressed",
    "build:css": "npm-run-all compile:sass prefix:css compress:css"
  },
  "author": "Jonas",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "autoprefixer": "^7.1.4",
    "concat": "^1.0.3",
    "live-server": "^1.2.1",
    "node-sass": "^4.5.3",
    "npm-run-all": "^4.1.1",
    "postcss-cli": "^4.1.1"
  }
```

After I `yarn start`, the problem is that the changes from `node_modules` are constantly detected, resulting refreshing the page. such as changes from `/node_modules/js-yaml`, `node_modules/concat-map`, `node_modules/lodash/fp`.

I wonder why the those node modules are changing all the time and is there a way to prevent the build to watch changes from `node_modules`?